# In mercurial, how to see tags for only a set of revisions instead of all?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

`hg tags` always shows all tags, so how can I get only the tags that point to a specific revision and all its ancestors?

The real-world use case is that if I use local tags to designate features (or bug fixes) on changesets, and I need to find out the cumulative features/bugs up till a specific rev.

One solution would be adding a wrapper command that adds "-r" to `tags`. Then what's the best way to implement it? Use revsets to get all ancestral revs and filter the tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick (requires mercurial 1.7):

```
hg log -r "ancestors(<rev>) and tag()"
```

where `<rev>` is the hash or local revision number. However, tagging every bugfix and feature seems overkill.

Instead of tagging, you can just follow a convention where you put "bugfix: xyz" or "feature: abc" in your commit messages. You can then extract all bugfixes and features like this:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(<rev>) and (keyword(bugfix) or keyword(feature))"
```

Keep tags for important milestones or other revisions that have some special significance.

Comment: Very cool. We did think of using commit message, but then we need to use a precommit hook to enforce it (we require that every push has a bug number), which seems a bit stifling, and tricky with multiple chagnesets that deal with multiple bugs/features. And we'll use **local** tags in the integration repo, and indeed reserve global tags for release releases.

Comment: BTW I need to see the actual tags, not just the revisions, so please add `--template '{tags}'` (from LVK's answer) for a more perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

- Specify a revision
- Filter the log to only that changeset + all its ancestors
- Extract all tags that are in those changesets

You can do that if you can limit yourself to tag names:

```
hg log -r "ancestors(HASH)" --template "{tags}"
```